# CVE-2015-4852: Evaluating Apps for Vunerability

Tags: java, security, deserialization, exploit

My understanding from the write-up and example exploits of [CVE-2015-4852 by Foxglove](http://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/) is that you need code which receives user-provided serialized objects *and* the Apache commons-collections present on the classpath to exploit.

With those two things, a request should be craft-able (although some may require trial and error / knowledge of system).

As [I commented in this question about Spring Vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666249/does-springframework-use-invokertransformer-from-commons-collections), for a product to be vulnerable, it doesn't have to use the `InvokerTransfomer` directly.  The problematic object is supplied by the exploit request.  All the "vulnerable app" has to do is supply the commons-collections JAR and logic which invokes `.readObject()` on that user-supplied instance of `InvokerTransformer`.

Assuming that I'm understand this correctly... is it sufficient to evaluate a product (for which you have source) based on tracing backwards from where the `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` method is called and conclude that product is likely vulnerable if there's any way that the stream could contain objects provided by an external user?

Comment: I'm really hoping VeraCode and other static analysis tools add this to their taint analysis.  It's very tricky and time-consuming to do this analysis manually even with dataflow analysis tooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if there is a path for untrusted data to reach a call to **ObjectStream.readObject()** and **InvokerTransformer** is on the classpath then the product or library is vulnerable.

If you have to accept untrusted data destined for deserialization then you may be able to block payloads that include **InvokerTransformer**.  You'd have to roll your own serializable format parser or find a safe library that can do it.

Another mitigation is to unserialize in a separate classloader to which **InvokerTransformer** is inaccessible.

*Far* better yet - as @PhaedrusPhacdelm discovered - is whitelisting allowable classes for deserialization:
http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2015/11/09/java_serialization_bug/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-lookahead/

Comment: And thus begins the game of Whack-a-mole.  Works until the next class like InvokerTransformer is found ...

Comment: Here's a great summary from a development point of view: http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2015/11/09/java_serialization_bug/ which links to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-lookahead/  .... showing the ideal way to handle this is not to block specific classes, but to only whitelist the classes that you're willing to accept via a `resolveClass()` on a cutom Object Stream.

Comment: @PhaedrusPhacdelm that is awesome.  Thank you for sharing those resources :)

Comment: @PhaedrusPhacdelm I think you've identified a fix that has legs here. I'm very fond of whitelisting. It's my preferred approach in a variety of security realms.

Comment: Props to Charles Miller (http://stackoverflow.com/users/3052/charles-miller) for the tip in the blog post above.

Comment: InvokerTransformer is just *one* way of exploiting the deserialization of untrusted data. Even if there is no InvokerTransformer available, there may be other classes which side-effects can be utilized in a malicious way.

Comment: @Gumbo right. But the OP's question is proof of existence of *this* particular vuln for which taint analysis leading to **InvokerTransformer** is sufficient. Detecting vulnerability in general for this would involve in-depth analysis of all **readObject()** methods in every **Serializable** on the classpath.  That is worthwhile, but a separate pursuit. Fair?

Comment: Does the application is impacted even when we don't use custom java object in serialization / de-serialization process.  eg: If my application is just de-serializing the String or other standard java object (Integer) from the stream, Am I still impacted due to this vulnerability (assuming InvokerTransformer is in the class path)?

Comment: @param83 if you are limited to using methods that explicitly require a specific type of serialized primitive or built-in type like **readBoolean**, **readByte()**, **readChar()**, **readDouble()**, **readFloat()**, **readInt()**, **readLong()**, **readShort()**, **readUnsignedByte**, **readUnsignedShort**, and **readUTF()**, then you should be okay. Those all read data literally and map it directly. Calling dynamic unserialization methods like **readObject()** or any methods that call it with untrusted data will leave you exposed to this vulnerability.